# Python like string format in typescript

Tags: typescript

In python I can do following

```
print "%02d:%02d" % (9, 6) # will output 09:06
```

How can I do this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [sprintf-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-js) library and [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sprintf-js).

Comment: This is actually very simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/1ytxfcwx/

**NPM:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-string-operations

**GITHUB:** https://github.com/sevensc/typescript-string-operations

Either use Template Strings -> https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html

or you can use a class a wrote -> [String.Format not work in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070158/string-format-not-work-in-typescrypt/35163695#35163695)

or use my NPM package!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-string-operations

`var value = String.Format("{0:L}", "APPLE"); //output "apple"`