# Replace all instances of character in string in typescript?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, replace, global

I'm trying to replace all full stops in an email with an x character - for example "my.email@email.com" would become "myxemail@emailxcom". Email is set to a string.
My problem is it's not replacing just full stops, it's replacing every character, so I just get a string of x's.
I can get it working with just one full stop, so I'm assuming I'm wrong on the global instance part. Here's my code:

```
let re = ".";
let new = email.replace(/re/gi, "x");
```

I've also tried

```
re = /./gi;
new = email.replace(re, "x");
```

If anyone can shed any light I'd really appreciate it, I've been stuck on this for so long and can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

** Edit: Whoops, my new variable was actually called newemail, keyword new wasn't causing the issue!

Comment: `new` is a reserved word in javascript

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Your second example is the closest. The first problem is your variable name, **`new`**, which happens to be one of JavaScript's [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) (and is instead used to construct objects, like `new RegExp` or `new Set`). This means that your program will throw a Syntax Error.

Also, since the dot (`.`) is a special character inside regex grammar, you should escape it as `\.`. Otherwise you would end up with `result == "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`, which is undesirable.

```js
let email = "my.email@email.com"

let re = /\./gi;
let result = email.replace(re, "x");

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I was going wrong with the /./gi, /\./ solved the issue! Thanks a million!

Comment: how to replace a character in a string based on index?

Comment: @George What do you mean? Can you give me a desired example/output?

Comment: `let theString = "george"` , i want to replace the third character for example `theString[2]="a"` so now it would be 'gearge'

Comment: in that case I would suggest: `let string = 'george'; let result = string.slice(0, 2) + 'a' + string.slice(3);`

Comment: thank you sounds good
currently i am transforming it to array then do the change then transforming it to string 
i'll try your way asap

Comment: Do not forget that `g` to make the expression global. I always do.

Answer (score 78):

You can try `split()` and `join()` method that was work for me. (For normal string text)
It was short and simple to implement and understand.
Below is an example.

```
let email = "my.email@email.com";
email = email.split('.').join('x');
```

So, it will replace all your `.` with `x`. So, after the above example, `email` variable will have value `myxemail@gmailxcom`

Comment: I think this should be the default approach for a basic search/replace over using any regex.

Comment: This is brilliant!!

Comment: Thanks. It works only if we assign the output string of join method to the variable again like email = email.split('.').join('x');

Comment: In case if you want just to remove a symbol globally, it's worth to not forget to add '', like this: `email.split('.').join('')`

Answer (score 14):

You may just use `replaceAll()` String function, described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

If you are getting
**Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string'**
error - go to `tsconfig.json` and within "lib" change or add "es2021".

Like this:

[image]

More info here: [Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616486/property-replaceall-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

Comment: But I already have "es2021" in "lib"

Comment: Then you shouldn't get Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string' error and may use replaceAll() String function.
Or you mean that you get this error despite you have "es2021" in "lib"?

Comment: Yes, I get it despite having es2021 in lib

Comment: Ensure that you are looking into correct tsconfig.json. Also that you have only one tsconfig.json in the project. Try to re-create the file again. And check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616486/property-replaceall-does-not-exist-on-type-string

Comment: When I put "es2021", it stopped recognizing the type `HTMLElement`. Wtf...

Comment: Oh, inserted `DOM` along with `ES2021` and it worked alright.

Comment: In VS Code I did "Command Palette -> Go to project configuration (tsconfig)" and it said the project doesn't have a configuration, so that was the problem, it wasn't detecting my config. The error "Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string'" was from some sort of default VS Code config and adding ES2021 to "lib" in my config file had no effect cause it wasn't being used.