# Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I want to use `replaceAll` in typescript and angular 10.

But I get this error: **Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string'**.

This is my code:

```
let date="1399/06/08"
console.log(date.replaceAll('/', '_'))
```

Output: 13990608

How can fix my typescript to show me this function?

Comment: TypeScript can't magically add a function that your browser doesn't implement. You'll need to implement one of the replacement methods mentioned in the linked question in [Michael D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63616514/215552).

Comment: `date.split('/').join('_')` you can use this as of now. Although you can update to chrome85.

Comment: I want to use in vscode I have this error in vscode

Comment: @behroozbc you can try with latest typescript version.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You should be able to add those typings through your `tsconfig.json`.
Add `"ES2021.String"` to `lib` inside `compilerOptions`.

Your tsconfig should then look something like this:

```json
{
    ...,
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...,
        "lib": [
          ...,
          "ES2021.String"
        ]
    }
}
```

The `replaceAll` method is defined inside `lib.es2021.string.d.ts` as follows:

```js
interface String {
    /**
     * Replace all instances of a substring in a string, using a regular expression or search string.
     * @param searchValue A string to search for.
     * @param replaceValue A string containing the text to replace for every successful match of searchValue in this string.
     */
    replaceAll(searchValue: string | RegExp, replaceValue: string): string;

    /**
     * Replace all instances of a substring in a string, using a regular expression or search string.
     * @param searchValue A string to search for.
     * @param replacer A function that returns the replacement text.
     */
    replaceAll(searchValue: string | RegExp, replacer: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string): string;
}
```

Comment: found the `lib.esnext.string.d.ts` file the functions are declared as in your code not sure what you mean by "add those typings through your tsconfig.json" can you elaborate

Comment: @KukulaMula I added a template to my answer. What I meant was, to add `ESNext.String` to `lib` inside you `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: This removes the lint error but when I try to run, I get an error saying `An unhandled exception occurred: tsconfig.json:21:7 - error TS6046: Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015',...` with a long list of options but none of them are `ESNext.String` and it won't compile.

Comment: @StackUnderflow Maybe your TS version is too low, I believe it was added in TS 2.4, following this [commit](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/451561ec8d793309ca9daa438f22764dd0ef440a#diff-c78e322b21c3cc648f5d6f259f3f1fea58f1165da8347b40385c08c2c8e76ef7)

Comment: @Josef mine is 3.8.3, not the latest but not too old.

Comment: @StackUnderflow Not sure, you might have an entirely different problem. Search for the `lib.esnext.string.d.ts` file inside `node_modules/typescript/lib`, if its not there your versions don't match up. Or update/reinstall TS as a whole.

Comment: @Josef You're right. I thought something was fishy because I updated it earlier,  now I realize the version Angular is using doesn't match the global version. `tsc -v` shows `4.3.5` but `ng --version` shows `3.8.3`. Any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: @Josef When I updated it I used `npm install -g typescript@latest` and this is what I find when I search for how to update the Angular typescript.

Comment: @StackUnderflow That should update TS for you global `ng` but if not specified otherwise angular will use your local version if they don't match. Therefore you should skip the `-g` flag when updating you local repo.

Comment: @Josef Yes, that looked like it was going to work but it seems like I need to upgrade Angular. I have Angular version 9.1.12 and it was complaining that it `requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.9.0 but 4.3.5 was found instead.` Thanks for your help.

Comment: this worked for me in react-native mixed ts and js project
I added them in `tsconfig.json` and `jsconfig.json` files as:

 `"lib": ["es6", "ES2021.String"]`

Comment: Surely this is just like adding a .d.ts file? It doesn't actually add a shim / polyfill for older browsers. iOS 12/13 still would need a polyfill. So I'm very confused why nobody else has mentioned that. Sure for Chrome this is fine but not older Safari.

Comment: Very old browsers would need a polyfill, but it' actually quite well [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren#browser_compatibility).

Comment: write in lowercase if it doesn't work "es2021.String"

Answer (score 134):

You may solve the problem using RegExp and [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global#description). The global flag is what makes `replace` run on all occurrences.

```
"1399/06/08".replace(/\//g, "_") // "1399_06_08"
```

Comment: this doesn't "resolve the problem". This is another way to replace all the occurrences. But if you want to continue using replaceAll, this doesn't resolve the issue of the OP.

Comment: This question is about TypeScript compatibility with `String.replaceAll()` not a request for a workaround.

Comment: @bokkie In my case it solved the issue. I'm using react native and changing the compiler options doesn't actually update the javascript, so this is really the *only* solution.

Answer (score 19):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll):

> As of August 2020 the `replaceAll()` method is supported by Firefox but
> not by Chrome. It will become available in Chrome 85.

Meanwhile you could find multiple other methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/6513921).

Screenshot for possible future readers:

[image]

Comment: how can fix my typescript to show me this function??

Comment: See also https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_string_replaceall

Comment: @behroozbc: AFAIK, `replaceAll()` is from ES2021 spec. If the latest version of TS doesn't support it, you can't do much except use one of the other methods.

Answer (score 11):

**Just Use this function**

```js
    let date="1399/06/08"
    
    console.log(date.split('/').join('_'))
```

Comment: This was my first thought to solve my problem, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way. Using a RegEx seems the way to go

Comment: The question asked is "How can fix my typescript to show me this function?". A valid answer obviously is not "use my function instead", even more when there is a clean answer to that (fix the ES version) :)

Answer (score 11):

That is because TypeScript does not recognize newer methods, than his current JavaScript version. `String.replaceAll()` is defined is ES2021.

You have to add the `lib` in `compilerOptions`, on the `tsconfig.json` file.

The value of `lib` must be either: `["ES2021"]`, or specifically the string typing `["ES2021.String"]`.

Add the following on the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2021"]
  ...
}
```

Comment: this isn't removing my error for some reason

Answer (score 7):

You can create a file

> myOwnTypes.d.ts

at the root of your angular project and add the following code:

```js
interface String {
    replaceAll(input: string, output : string): any;
}
```

That will tell typescript that strings has this property.

Now **replaceAll** is supported in Chrome and Firefox but  is always good to check the caniuse to check if it fits your needs.

https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll

If this works for you upvotes are more than welcome, Im starting with this stackoverflow account and would appreciate the support :)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still having this issue, add this to your tsconfig.json

```
{
    ...,
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...,
        "lib": [
          ...,
          "esnext.string"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution: I had this issue but my tsconfig target was set to "es2021". The cause, there was also one lib being specified. So by using the lib and the target, it overrided the defaults to the lib. The solution completely remove the lib or add it to the lib options.

Example:
"compilerOptions":{
..."target": "ES2021"
}

or

"complierOptions":{
"target": "ES2021",
"lib":  [
...,
"ES2021.String"
],

Comment: This worked for me. I also had to make sure that my package was set to Node > 15 as well my active Node interpreter with nvm

Comment: wow this worked for me too, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A simple alternative to replace all using RegExp.

```js
let subject = '1399/06/08';

let substring = '/';
let replacement = '_';

let newSubject = subject.replace(new RegExp(substring, 'g'), replacement);

console.log(newSubject);
```

Notice that you can make it as a function that takes substring and replacement as string inputs, which is practical.

My use-case was creating an Angular "Replace" Pipe.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen with a correct `tsconfig` if the file is not used/imported anywhere and not part of `tsconfig.files`

Comment: This helped solve my problem, thanks. My issue was I was missing files in the `includes` part of my `tsconfig.json`. Updating `includes` by adding my scripts directory fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome supports replaceAll so it is safe to use. However typescript still issues an error, so you may cast your string to any, in order to overcome that obstacle.

```
const date: any ="1399/06/08"
console.log(date.replaceAll('/','_'))
```

Comment: please do not suggest to use `any`

Comment: Changing to any is not a solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN Web Docs,

> "to perform a global search and replace, include the `g` switch in the
> regular expression".

So, you can try doing:

```js
const date="1399/06/08"
const forwardSlashRegex = /(\/)/g;
console.log(date.replace(forwardSlashRegex, '_'));
```

This automatically replaces all forward slashes with the underscore. Make sure to also keep the `/g` global indicator at the end of the regex, as it allows JS to know that you want to replace ALL places where the forward slash occurs.

For more info on the use of regex indicators, refer to the following very useful guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions, you need to set the `target` attribute in `compilerOptions`.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021", // add this line to use ES2021
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "paths": {
        "@/*": ["src/*"],
        "@auth/*": ["src/auth/*"],
        "@aws/*": ["src/aws/*"],
        "@common/*": ["src/common/*"],
        "@conig/*": ["src/conig/*"],
        "@schemas/*": ["src/schemas/*"],
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems like the issue is due to primitive string. I converted my string variable to String object and then the replaceAll() method did not cause runtime error.