# Using string.replaceAll in Angular 15?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616486/property-replaceall-does-not-exist-on-type-string) we should set the following `compilerOptions` and it should work, however no love:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "ES2021",
    "lib": ["es2021", "dom", "esnext.string", "es2021.string"],    ...
  },
```

[This is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpzfjn?file=src%2Fmain.ts,tsconfig.json).  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty weird indeed.

And the fix doesn't seem obvious.

A *dirty* option could be to add in your `.ts`. But I'm not a fan of this 'hack'

```
/// <reference lib="es2022" />
```

Comment: You want `"lib": ["es2021.string"]`

Comment: Yeah I ended up just using `split` and `join` instead ... which was fine for my use case ... Aluan I tried adding `es2021.string`, but still no love ... see the updated demo ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpzfjn?file=src%2Fmain.ts,tsconfig.json