# JavaScript: Is exist a simple way to use string as format?

Tags: javascript, typescript

JavaScript (ES6), TypeScript

I have the localized resources of `string` type. I need to use these strings as a *format*. This is the example of my localized string: `getValue: The '{0}' key not found in the '{1}' map.` I need replace `{0}` and `{1}` by the values. Is exist any simple way to do it without using of `replace()` or `indexOf()` + `splice()`?

P.S. [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) cannot be used in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: Take a look at [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and see if those fit your use case.

Comment: No. Template strings in JS can help sometimes but interpolated at the point they are defined and do not have a simple `printf` formatting method because reasons. Just use handlebars like everybody else.

Comment: @zero298 I know about it and it can't be used in this case.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070158/string-format-not-work-in-typescrypt#answer-20070599 for both string literals, and a string format polyfill.

Comment: I would edit your question just to be clearer that these strings have to be transformed at run time and why Template Literals won't work.  You have an interesting question, but I wouldn't want it to get hammered with answers telling you to use literals when they won't work.

Comment: @zero298 I added "P.S.".