# String.Format like C# in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to use similar function like String.Format of C# in TypeScript?

My idea is to make some string like:

```
url = "path/{0}/{1}/data.xml"
```

depending of the logical I set {0} and {1}. Obiouslly I can replace them but I think String.Format is a clear function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expanding on the comment that I made on the response from vivekkurien, declaring a function which, in turn, interpolates is probably the largest "bang for your buck" approach.  I use this, frequently, for generating chunks of repetitive HTML with minor varying properties, for example.

The answer from vivekkurien, however, does not work.  It returns a literal string, instead.  Here is a modified sample, based on the original answer:

```typescript
const pathFn = (param1, param2) => `path/${param1}/${param2}/data.xml`;

let param1 = "student";
let param2 = "contantdetails";
let resultPath = pathFn(param1, param2);

alert(resultPath);
```

A runnable example of the above code can be found here: [Function-Based Interpolation at TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20pathFn%20%3D%20(param1%2C%20param2)%20%3D%3E%20%60path%2F%24%7Bparam1%7D%2F%24%7Bparam2%7D%2Fdata.xml%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20param1%20%3D%20%22student%22%3B%0D%0Alet%20param2%20%3D%20%22contantdetails%22%3B%0D%0Alet%20resultPath%20%3D%20pathFn(param1%2C%20param2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(resultPath)%3B)

Comment: String.format you can use an array and  position 0 i the format and the next one are the values but all in an array of basic objects. Is it possible to do in Typescript?

Comment: Not natively, that I am aware of. That being said, check out the second response to this question, which sounds very close to what you are looking for, there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070158/string-format-not-work-in-typescript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 22):

I think you are looking for back quote: ``

```js
var firstname = 'Fooo';
var lastname = 'Bar';

console.log(`Hi ${firstname} ${lastname}. Welcome.`);
```

You can find the back quote on the tilde key.
[image]

Comment: String.format you can use an array and  position 0 i the format and the next one are the values but all in an array of basic objects.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for!!Thank you!!

Answer (score 16):

```
const StringFormat = (str: string, ...args: string[]) =>
  str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (match, index) => args[index] || '')

let res = StringFormat("Hello {0}", "World!")
console.log(res) // Hello World!
res = StringFormat("Hello {0} {1}", "beautiful", "World!")
console.log(res) // Hello beautiful World!
res = StringFormat("Hello {0},{0}!", "beauty")
console.log(res) //Hello beauty,beauty!
res = StringFormat("Hello {0},{0}!", "beauty", "World!")
console.log(res) //Hello beauty,beauty!
```

Try in [TypeScript Playgroud](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20StringFormat%20%3D%20(str%3A%20string%2C%20...args%3A%20string%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20str.replace(%2F%7B(%5Cd%2B)%7D%2Fg%2C%20(match%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20args%5Bindex%5D%20%7C%7C%20'')%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20res%20%3D%20StringFormat(%22Hello%20%7B0%7D%22%2C%20%22World!%22)%0D%0Aconsole.log(res)%20%2F%2F%20Hello%20World!%0D%0Ares%20%3D%20StringFormat(%22Hello%20%7B0%7D%20%7B1%7D%22%2C%20%22beautiful%22%2C%20%22World!%22)%0D%0Aconsole.log(res)%20%2F%2F%20Hello%20beautiful%20World!%0D%0Ares%20%3D%20StringFormat(%22Hello%20%7B0%7D%2C%7B0%7D!%22%2C%20%22beauty%22)%0D%0Aconsole.log(res)%20%2F%2FHello%20beauty%2Cbeauty!%0D%0Ares%20%3D%20StringFormat(%22Hello%20%7B0%7D%2C%7B0%7D!%22%2C%20%22beauty%22%2C%20%22World!%22)%0D%0Aconsole.log(res)%20%2F%2FHello%20beauty%2Cbeauty!)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the path as a function which can accept 2 parameter.
Then it will return as string if we call the function with required parameters.

```
const pathFn= (param1, param2) => "path/${param1}/${param2}/data.xml";
let param1 = "student";
let param2 = "contantdetails";
let resultPath = pathFn(param1,param2);
```

Comment: You would want to use bat quotes for the string interpolation to kick in, as well as use the interpolation marker ($) for the replacement to happen.  See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20pathFn%20%3D%20(param1%2C%20param2)%20%3D%3E%20%60path%2F%24%7Bparam1%7D%2F%24%7Bparam2%7D%2Fdata.xml%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20param1%20%3D%20%22student%22%3B%0D%0Alet%20param2%20%3D%20%22contantdetails%22%3B%0D%0Alet%20resultPath%20%3D%20pathFn(param1%2C%20param2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(resultPath)%3B

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Tried with different scenarios.

```
format(text: string, ...args: string[]): string {
    return text.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (match, num) => {
      return typeof args[num] !== 'undefined' ? args[num] : match;
    });
  }
```