# How to write a string.format(...) for value of an HTML attribute?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've created a datalist whose label has the form : "City name (city code)"

```html
<!-- Sélecteur de communes du COG -->
<input type="text" list="communesCOG" [(ngModel)]="commune" (click)="selectCodeCommune(commune)">
<datalist id="communesCOG" >
    <option *ngFor="let commune of communes | keyvalue"
        [value]="commune.value.codeCommune"
        [label]="commune.value.nomCommune + ' (' + commune.value.codeCommune  + ')'">
    </option>
</datalist>
```

But the :

```
[label]="commune.value.nomCommune + ' (' + commune.value.codeCommune  + ')'"
```

disappoint me. According to [String.Format not work in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070158/string-format-not-work-in-typescript/30886122) I could use a `string.format(...)` instead.

I tried this, but without success (it was refused) :

```
[label]="'{0} ({1})'.format(commune.value.nomCommune, commune.value.codeCommune)"
```

What is the proper way to use a `format(...)` function on an HTML attribute with *Angular* ?

Comment: Did you tried using TypeScript's string interpolation?

Comment: @Bozhinovski : It doesn't seems to work. Do you have a working sample for this case ?

Comment: This looks correct for me:  [label]="commune.value.nomCommune + ' (' + commune.value.codeCommune  + ')'".  What is this for a pipe:keyvalue?     Can you try to remove this pipe: "| keyvalue " ?

Comment: It works, but it's not compliant for internationalization. Later, the page might display  : "Commune : Brest, (29056)", or : "City : Brest (29056)", depending on the language of the user. This is why the statement has to change into something like `textFormat.format(arg1, arg2)`. The pipe keyvalue is here because I am reading values to display from a Map.

Comment: `label="{{commune.value.nomCommune}} ({{commune.value.codeCommune}})"` will definitely work with angular's native i18n, if this is your concern. You'll be able to change the actual displayed text to anything you want from the translations files

Answer (score 0):

you always can create a function. e.g.(*)

```
format(text: string, ...args: any[]) {
    if (text.match(/\{.\}/))
      text.match(/\{.\}/g).forEach((l,i)=>{
        text=text.replace(l,args[i])
      })
    return text
  }
```

If you has, e.g.

```
translation={
    en:
    {
      list:'one:{0}, two:{1}'
    },
    es:
    {
      list:'uno:{0}, dos:{1}'
    }
  }
  lang=this.translation.es
```

You can has an .html as

```
<button (click)="lang=lang==translation.en?
                   translation.es:translation.en">
    click
 </button>
 <p>{{format(lang.list,'hello','word')}}
```

See a [example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snxwdw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

(*) The function replace **in order** the arguments, so it's equal if we write {0}{1} or {1}{0} or even {z}{s}

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is to use internationalization later on and you plan to use angular's native i18n, then this should work

```
label="{{commune.value.nomCommune}} ({{commune.value.codeCommune}})" i18n-label
```

Once texts are extracted you can modify your language translation files to display whatever you want.

**Using .format() in your code**

Now, if you want to use `.format` on a string, you need to follow these steps:

**Step #1 Declare the method in a *.d.ts file**

**src/mytypes.d.ts**

```
interface String {
  format(...replacements: string[]): string;
}
```

You need to make sure that your `tsconfig.app.json` file already includes declaration files

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*.d.ts"
]
```

**Step #2 Implement the method somewhere**

You can add some implementation (the one below if from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070599/1160794)) to your polyfills file for instance

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
        ;
    });
  };
}
```

After that, you should be able to use `"mystring".format` in your ts code and template files